# Compiling a Win32 GUI app (without a console) using MinGW and Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, mingw

I'm using the eclipse IDE with MinGW as my compiler, to make a Win32 GUI app.

I want to get rid of the console, but compiling the program with `-mwindows` option has no effect and the console is still there.

Using the `-Wl,--subsystem,windows` flag also produces no effect. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What GUI toolkit you're using?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For gcc on Windows, two things should be considered to build a non-console Windows app:

1. Compiler option `-mwindows`
2. Have `WinMain()`

It is possible, however, to manually specify `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` to the linker and include `gdi32` and `comdlg32` into the build. This is exactly what `-mwindows` automates.

[Reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-01/msg00225.html).

Answer (score 2):

try --machine-windows option. it helps me when I build asm code:

```
nasm -f win64 hello.asm
gcc hello.obj --machine-windows -o hello
```