# trying to make a console window not appear [c++]

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, winapi

Hi guys I'm just starting a project and the first part of the project requires no console window to be shown when the executable is run(has to be on a windows machine), but I can't seem to accomplish this, I am using `eclipse kepler` on a 64 bit windows machine.

I first added the windows main to my main function then I followed this thread:

[Compiling a Win32 GUI app (without a console) using MinGW and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474504/compiling-a-win32-gui-app-without-a-console-using-mingw-and-eclipse)

But maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I left the linker flags blank, I then clicked settings selected a new other options and put this in `-subsystem, win32`. But that had no success!

I then changed it to `-subsystem, win32` with a capital `W` but no luck.

I then tried adding `-mwindows` as the flag and repeated the steps above but no success.

Any idea what how I can fix this Thanx.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;


int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
        int       nCmdShow) {

    return 0;    
}
```

hi randrop I tried using that code but when I try to run the program a .exe file is not being executed ,I'm not too sure why

********** edit

Hi guys so it turns out it is working but since the program does nothing it terminates right away is there anyway I can keep the programming executing without a console window showing??

Comment: The linker switch is `-subsystem,windows`, as explained in the Q&A you linked to. Why didn't you follow it?

Comment: I did,it didn't work

Comment: when I add -mwindows as the flag and -subsystem,windows as other option it tells me launch failed: binary file not found,and when I check my folders there is no .exe file,even when I clean and rebuild the project nothing..

Comment: Your WinMain() function does nothing but exit, so of course the program exits immediately.  *Usually,* of course, you want the program to do something, so WinMain() won't be empty.  If you just want a "Hello, world!" style program, call `MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello World!", L"My Program", MB_OK);` (You might need to leave out the L prefixes if the program is being built in ANSI rather than Unicode mode.)

Answer (score -1):

To remove the console this option -mwindows have to be passed in the linker options