# errors: -undefined reference to `_imp__GetStockObject@4' and undefined reference to `_imp__SetBkMode@8'

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++17

i wrote a code in visual studio code in windows10 in c++ to get simple window but unable to build and run
all the files used to debug are provided like task.json,launch.json and cpp-properties.json
plz tell me how to make windows project in visual studio code.

Errors are

```
> Executing task: g++ -g -lgdi32 main.cpp <

C:\Users\abhi\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0d0bc2.o: In function `WinMain@16':
C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\abs/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `_imp__GetStockObject@4'
C:\Users\abhi\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0d0bc2.o: In function `Z10WindowProcP6HWND__jjl@16':
C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\abs/main.cpp:91: undefined reference to `_imp__SetBkMode@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message,
  WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// Listing OFWIN_1
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  WNDCLASSEX WindowClass;                        // Structure to hold our window's attributes

  static LPCTSTR szAppName { _T("OFWin") };      // Define window class name
  HWND hWnd;                                     // Window handle
  MSG msg;                                       // Windows message structure

  WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);       // Set structure size

  // Redraw the window if the size changes
  WindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

  // Define the message handling function
  WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;

  WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;                    // No extra bytes after the window class
  WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;                    // structure or the window instance

  WindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;             // Application instance handle

  // Set default application icon
  WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);

  // Set window cursor to be the standard arrow
  WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);

  // Set gray brush for background color
  WindowClass.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));

  WindowClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;            // No menu
  WindowClass.lpszClassName = szAppName;         // Set class name
  WindowClass.hIconSm = nullptr;                 // Default small icon

  // Now register our window class
  RegisterClassEx(&WindowClass);

  // Now we can create the window
  hWnd = CreateWindow(
    szAppName,                                   // the window class name
    _T("A Basic Window the Hard Way"),           // The window title
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,                         // Window style as overlapped
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                               // Default screen position of upper left
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                               // corner of our window as x,y.
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                               // Default window size width ...
    CW_USEDEFAULT,                               // ... and height
    nullptr,                                     // No parent window
    nullptr,                                     // No menu
    hInstance,                                   // Program Instance handle
    nullptr                                      // No window creation data
    );

  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);                    // Display the window
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);                            // Redraw window client area 

  // The message loop
  while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) == TRUE) // Get any messages
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);                      // Translate the message
    DispatchMessage(&msg);                       // Dispatch the message
  }

  return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);           // End, so return to Windows
}

// Listing OFWIN_2
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message,
  WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

  switch (message)                               // Process selected messages
  {
  case WM_PAINT:                                 // Message is to redraw the window
    HDC hDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT PaintSt;                         // Structure defining area to be drawn
    hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &PaintSt) ;           // Prepare to draw the window

    // Get upper left and lower right of client area
    RECT aRect;                                  // A working rectangle
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &aRect);

    SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);                 // Set text background mode

    // Now draw the text in the window client area
    DrawText(
      hDC,                                       // Device context handle
      _T("But, soft! What light through yonder window breaks?"),
      -1,                                        // Indicate null terminated string
      &aRect,                                    // Rectangle in which text is to be drawn
      DT_SINGLELINE |                            // Text format - single line
      DT_CENTER |                                //             - centered in the line
      DT_VCENTER);                               //             - line centered in aRect

    EndPaint(hWnd, &PaintSt);                    // Terminate window redraw operation
    return 0;

  case WM_DESTROY:                               // Window is being destroyed
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

task.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++ -g main.cpp",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "echo",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

cpp properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include\\c++"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are *using* Visual Studio Code, but this question isn't really *about* VSCode, since the problem can be reproduced by running your first command at a command prompt (Windows `cmd.exe` or Cygwin `bash`):

```
  > g++ -g -lgdi32 main.cpp
  (errors as above)
```

Since you're trying to [build a Windows program using MinGW gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474504/compiling-a-win32-gui-app-without-a-console-using-mingw-and-eclipse), you need to pass the `-mwindows` option:

```
  > g++ -g -mwindows main.cpp
  (works)
  > ./a.exe
  (runs)
```

Add the `-mwindows` to your `tasks.json` command and it should work from within VSCode too.

Comment: There is more to it.  Mysteries I see are how linker managed to find the libraries, even though the search path was never specified, why the imports from user32 did not generate the same errors, how it figured out to link user32 even though it wasn't specified, why the missing symbols have 32-bit name decoration even though he used a 64-bit compiler.  All I can guess at is that the OP decided to arbitrarily copy files to solve problems, turning it into a big ball of wax.  Good luck.

Comment: @HansPassant Using mingw64-5.4.0 `g++ -std=c++11`, I get almost the exact same errors as the OP reports with the OP's code and command line.  The libraries are coming from the linker's default search path (visible with `g++ -v`).  I don't know about the other issues you raise.