# windows.h program compiles but doesnt run

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a program with the windows API and it has two files. The first program is a function to draw a pixel, and the second program handles the window. I'm compiling using  g++ main.cpp graphics.cpp -o main -lgdi32, it will compile but when I try to run it nothing happens, there are no errors.
Graphics.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
static HWND hwnd { 0 };
void DrawPixel(HWND hwnd, int x, int y);

int WINAPI 
WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {

    MSG  msg;
    WNDCLASSW wc = {0};

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Pixels";
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Pixels",
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                100, 100, 300, 250, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(msg) {

        case WM_PAINT:

            
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:

            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void DrawPixel(int x, int y) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT r;

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);

    if (r.bottom == 0) {
    
        return;
    }

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    
    SetPixel(hdc, x, y, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windef.h>

void DrawPixel(int x, int y);

int main(){
    DrawPixel(100, 100);
}
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the windows handle and how I am retrieving it but no matter how I refactor my code it wont work.
Edit: It turns out the issue is that the WinMain function isnt running.

Comment: First you need to decide if you're compiling a Windows subsystem program or a Console subsystem program. That determines whether the entry point is WinMain or main. You probably want to target Windows so WinMain is the entry point. Then you need to actually draw inside the `WM_PAINT` handler.

Comment: Inside your `main` function, add some console output, such as `std::cout << "This program runs main, not WinMain. It does not use Windows' GUI.\n";`. Maybe add different console output in your other functions, just to see which, if any, run (i.e. try to eliminate the "nothing happens" symptom).

Comment: Look here : [GDI Setpixel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixel). You need to draw to a Device context. Which you get from your window using : [GetDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc)

Comment: @RetiredNinja how do I compile for windows subsystem in mingw?

Comment: I believe if the compiler finds a `WinMAin` function and no `main` function it will handle it automatically. You could also try adding `-mwindows` to the command line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474504/compiling-a-win32-gui-app-without-a-console-using-mingw-and-eclipse